# Children Sum Parent in a Tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-tree

The problem is to determine if the sum of the child data is equal to parent data. if so, return true, else return false.

Below is my code which is giving an error upon submission. i know this is a simple question but after writing the condition, i am having difficulty in how to recursively check the sum condition for every node in the binary tree by traversing all the left and right nodes.

```html
int isSumProperty(Node *node)
{
    if(node == NULL) return 0;
    if((node->left->data + node->right->data) == node->data)
    {
        return 1;
        
    }
    else
    {
        return isSumProperty(node->left)&&isSumProperty(node->right);
    }
    
}
```

Please guide me as in where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. By child data, do mean immediate children or all descendants? What error are you getting?

Comment: i mean immediate child. i am getting segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `node->left->data` without ensuring that `node->left` is not `NULL`.

That's resulting in a segmentation fault.

Comment: yes, correct. i will take care of that situation and after that how to i return two values recursively, one for left and the other for right?

Comment: @user2978343 I'll ask again. What exactly do you have to return? If it's an answer for root, you are already doing that. If the question is whether any node in tree satisfies this, then you could use `or` between results of left and right. But first, what, precisely, is the question?

Comment: i am really sorry merlyn. i have to return 1 if child parent sum is equal else return 0. i already mentioned this in the start of my question

Comment: @user2978343 In that case, why are you recursing over children. Once the sum of left and right is not equal to root, the answer should be 0 right?

Comment: Also, i have one more doubt, if i encounter a leaf node, i should return false right?

Comment: i have to recurse over all the children in the tree for checking the condition, if all nodes satisfy this condition return true else return false.

Comment: @user2978343 ok. Then you should only be recursing in case the root satisfies the property. Because if the root doesn't, it's pointless to check anything else.

Comment: yes, i didn't think of it. Appreciate your insight on this. i have one last doubt.if i encounter a leaf node, i should return true or false?

Comment: @user2978343 I would assume true, but again, this is the sort of thing I expect to be mentioned in the question explicitly.

Comment: Actually, it was mentioned that for NULL children , data value is considered as 0. then in that case, lets a leaf node with parent data as 5, and its children data will 0, in this case , sum is not equal right? then we have to return false?

Comment: @user2978343 But then the answer will always be false. After all, every tree will have leaves. Unless everything has data 0, it can't work. My assumption would be that leaves are considered to be true by default.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks. my code got accepted and as you said, leaves are considered to be true by default.